# Having problem in connecting my SQL Database with XAMPP

Tags: php

I am trying to connect to my SQL database using from my Google Chrome extension. I am getting the following error:

> (Your file was not found It may have been moved or deleted. ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

This appears when I click login on HTML file, instead of the output message I'm trying to achieve with PHP

(Login page.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/Style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icon-font.css">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Elite Bug Tracker</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        
        <div class="container">
    
            <div class="Content">
                
                <div class="Column1">
    
                    <img src="img/bug.png" class="bug">
    
                    <h2>ELITE BUG TRACKER</h2>
                    
                    </div> 
    
                
                <div class="Column2">
                    
                    <h1>Login Here</h1>
                    
                    <form action="login.php" method="POST"> 
                        
                        <div class="login">
                            <p>USERNAME</p>
                                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Email" id="username" required/>
                            
                            <p>PASSWORD</p>
                                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" id="password" required />
                        </div>     
                            
                        <div class="Enter">
                            
                            <button type="Submit" value="login">Login</button> 
                        </div>     
                        
                        <div class="Links">
                            
                            <ul>
                                
                            <li><a href="#">Log in as demo user</a></li>
                            
                            <li><a href="#">Forgot password</a></li>
                            
                            <li><a href="#">Register as new user</a></li>
                                
                            </ul>
                            
                        </div> 
                        
                        
                    </form></div>
    
                
                </div>
    
     
            </div>
            
    
       
        
    </body>
        
    </html>
```

(login.php)

```
<?php
session_start();
// Change this to your connection info.
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'Bug Tracker App';
// Try and connect using the info above.
$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// Now we check if the data from the login form was submitted, isset() will check if the data exists.
if (!isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    exit('Please fill both the username and password field!');
}
// Prepare our SQL, preparing the SQL statement will prevent SQL injection.
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), in our case the username is a string so we use "s"
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    $stmt->store_result();
    // If the username exiusts
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
        $stmt->fetch();
        // Account exists, now we verify the password.
        // Note: remember to use password_hash in your registration file to store the hashed passwords.
        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
            // Verification success! User has loggedin!
            // Create sessions so we know the user is logged in, they basically act like cookies but remember the data on the server.
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            header('Location: home.php');
        } else {
            echo 'Incorrect password!';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect username!';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
}
?>
```

Comment: Is login.php in the same directory as loginpage.html?

Comment: ...no, it's on a different scheme/host  if loginpage.html is part of the extension.  Just put an iframe in the extension and run the code from the server.

Comment: @JohnConde correct same directory.